# How to output PHP inside JS/jQuery that generates HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I have to run a PHP action that is inside HTML which is inside a JS script. The current code does an error because the function that renders HTML breaks the syntax. I am getting ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='***

Here is my code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('.menu-main').on('click', function() {
        var page   = window.location.href;
        var mobile = $('.menu-item-mobile');
        var search = '<div class="wpml-language-switcher">'<?php do_action('wpml_add_language_selector'); ?>'</div>';

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(mobile.find('form').length == 1) return;
            mobile.html(search);
        }, 50);  //delay time   
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here is the output with failed structure in line 8 ***(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=')***:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('.av-burger-menu-main').on('click', function() {
        var page   = window.location.href;
        var mobile = $('.menu-item-search-mobile');
        var search = '<div class="wpml-floating-language-switcher">'
<div
     class="wpml-ls-statics-shortcode_actions wpml-ls wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown js-wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown" id="lang_sel">
    <ul>

        <li tabindex="0" class="wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-lv wpml-ls-current-language wpml-ls-first-item wpml-ls-item-legacy-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="js-wpml-ls-item-toggle wpml-ls-item-toggle lang_sel_sel icl-lv">
                                                    <img
            class="wpml-ls-flag iclflag"
            src="https://sampledomain.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/lv.png"
            alt=""
            width=18
            height=12
    /><span class="wpml-ls-native icl_lang_sel_native">LV</span></a>

            <ul class="wpml-ls-sub-menu">
                
                    <li class="icl-en wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-en">
                        <a href="https://sampledomain.com/en/" class="wpml-ls-link">
                                                                <img
            class="wpml-ls-flag iclflag"
            src="https://sampledomain.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/en.png"
            alt=""
            width=18
            height=12
    /><span class="wpml-ls-native icl_lang_sel_native" lang="en">EN</span></a>
                    </li>

                
                    <li class="icl-ru wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-ru wpml-ls-last-item">
                        <a href="https://sampledomain.com/ru/" class="wpml-ls-link">
                                                                <img
            class="wpml-ls-flag iclflag"
            src="https://sampledomain.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/ru.png"
            alt=""
            width=18
            height=12
    /><span class="wpml-ls-native icl_lang_sel_native" lang="ru">RU</span></a>
                    </li>

                            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
'</div>';

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(mobile.find('form').length == 1) return;
            mobile.html(search);
        }, 50);  //delay time   
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Is there anything possible to avoid the syntax error?

Comment: Change to `var search = '<div class="wpml-language-switcher"><?php do_action('wpml_add_language_selector'); ?></div>'`. The HTML being output from the PHP function is HTML, so it needs to be part of the string you're assigning to `search`. Because you closed the string with a quote mark, JS is trying to interpret the following HTML as JS code (and, inevitably, failing).

Comment: It gets me to Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at (index):8:16)

Comment: You could eliminate that I think by removing the line breaks from the HTML which PHP outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I'd put the PHP contents into a template tag and grab the contents with jQuery. For example...

```php
<script type="text/template" id="template-wpml_add_language_selector">
    <?php do_action('wpml_add_language_selector'); ?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('.menu-main').on('click', function() {
        var templateContents = $('#template-wpml_add_language_selector').html();
        var page   = window.location.href;
        var mobile = $('.menu-item-mobile');
        var search = '<div class="wpml-language-switcher">' + templateContents + '</div>';

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(mobile.find('form').length == 1) return;
            mobile.html(search);
        }, 50);  //delay time   
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```